# Rails auto complete User object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my application users belongs to a group and this is done in my Usergroup Model.

```
class Usergroup < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :usergroups
  has_many :groups, through: :usergroups
end

class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :usergroups
  has_many :users, through: :usergroups
end
```

When I want to add a `user` to the `group` though I need to know the ID of the `group` and the ID of the `user` which is less than ideal. I created a autocomplete field using jQuery to take care of this for me.

```
<%= form_with(model: usergroup, local: true) do |form| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :user_id %>
    <%= form.text_field :user_id, id: 'user', data: { autocomplete_source: User.order(:email).map(&:email) } %>
  </div>

  <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

When I attempt to create the new `usergroup` with the email I selected from this dropdown menu it's submitting because it's requiring there to be a user. How do I pass the complete user object to this field instead of just the email of the user I want to create? Am I approaching this correctly?

This is the route that is being used to get the users.

```
user GET    /users/:id(.:format)      users#index
```

Comment: You may want to achieve it with id or email rather than user object. Since form helpers are actually rendering HTML code, serializing user objects and sending them over form data is kind of a waste.

Comment: The standard method is to populate a hidden field with the user_id value and continue to display the email in the auto complete box. I don’t know what you’re using to power the autocomplete so can’t provide code examples

Comment: @TomDunning I am just using jQuery Autocomplete. You can see where the data is coming from in the post. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When I have to find a value from a large list I like to use the gem ["select2-rails" gem](https://github.com/argerim/select2-rails)

you can make an Ajax code to get your values like this

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :json

  def index
    if params[:email].present?
      @users = User.where(email: params[:email])
    else
      @users = User.all
    end
    respond_with @users
  end
end
```

in your HTML all you need

```
<div class="field">
  <%= form.label :user_id %>
  <%= form.hidden_field :user_id, id: 'user_id', class: 'select2' %>
</div>
```

and in your JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.select2').select2({
    ajax: {
      url: "<%= user_path(format: :json) %>",
      dataType: "json",
      results: function(data, page) {
        return { 
          results: $.map( data, function(user, i) { 
            return { id: user.id, text: user.email } 
          } )
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

I hope that this works for you or points you in the right direction

Comment: I just made a update to use the index method. I hope that this helps you out. Let me know if anything else

Comment: When typing in an email in the select2 dropdown I am not getting any results?

Comment: is it hitting your controller?

Comment: just to test you can do `url: "<%= user_path(email: 'some_email@test.com', format: :json) %>",`

Comment: I am still unable to get data to render with this method otherwise it would be the accepted answer.

Comment: have you tried the above? where you hard code the request?

Comment: I have. If I put that `some_email@test.com` url in the Javascript it still returns no results.

Comment: Regardless if the email parameter is present it should still be returning something, correct? Becuase it is not even doing that. Seems like a routing or Ajax issue?

Comment: Are we hitting the ja method

Comment: If I add `console.log("Test hit");` after `$(document).ready(function() {` in my JS it prints to the console log. This signifies that it is hitting it, yeah?

Comment: maybe we can find a way to pair tomorrow

Comment: Can we try to pair this now?

Answer (score 2):

Typically when you have an autocomplete, you want to use a select box for this. One of the advantages of a select box is that you can display one value and the select will actually submit a different one. This is perfect for your situation where you want to have the user select an email but you actually want to receive a user_id server side.

```
<%= form.collection_select :user_id, User.order(:email), :id, :email %>
```

You can wrap a select like this with libraries like Selectize or Select2 to provide an autocomplete style dropdown.

I believe the jQuery Autocomplete library would work for this too, but I'm not terribly familiar with it. This looks like what you'd want where each item is an object with a value and a label. https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data

It might look like this with your existing JS that loads the `autocomplete_source` attribute, but no guarantees this will work.

```
<%= form.collection_select :user_id, User.order(:email), :id, :email, data: { autocomplete_source: User.order(:email).map{ |u| { value: u.id, label: u.email } } %>
```